# Left hand menu link color chnage in angular

Tags: angularjs

For my angular application , i have created left nav menu. On click of link ,corresponding page is opening. My problem is I want to change active link color to blue whereas other links are in white color. When I click another link from menu ,that link should be in blue and remaining are in white.
I do not know how to do this in angular. With Jquery , its easy for me. But angular makes me nervous.

My left nav is

```
<div class="leftNavList">
          <div class="leftNavManageHeading"><span "mSans300 font14">Manage</span></div>
          <ul class="nav manageNav">

             <li ng-click="isCollapsed2 = !isCollapsed2">
              <div class="listOuterWrapper">
                <div class="listInnerWraper">

                <span class="mSans300">Usage</span>

                </div>
              </div> 
             </li>              
             <li ng-click="isCollapsed3 = !isCollapsed3">
              <div class="listOuterWrapper">

                <span class="mSans300">Payment</span>
               </div> 
               <div class="listInnerWraper">
               <div collapse="!isCollapsed3">
                   <ul class="paymentNav mSans30 font14">
                     <li><a href="#/paymentMethod" class="">PaymentMethod</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#/paymentHistory" class="">PaymentHistory</a></li>

                   </ul>
                </div>
               </div>   
              </li>              
             <li ng-click="isCollapsed4 = !isCollapsed4">
              <div class="listOuterWrapper">
                <div class="listInnerWraper">

                  <span class="mSans300"><a href="#/editAccount" class="">Account</a></span>

                </div>
              </div>
             </li>                                             
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you using ngRoute or ui-router? a simple way would be to use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) then you can check if location is the same as the current url and use ng-class to add a class to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In ng-init declare a variable.

```
ng-init="activelink=0"
```

Step 2:  Now in ng-cick of link change the value of activelink.

```
<li><a href="" ng-click="activelink=1"</a></li>
<li><a href="" ng-click="activelink=2"</a></li>
```

Step 3: Declare a class linkcolor that defines the color of the active link.

Step 4: Now use ng-class="{ 'linkcolor' : activelink==1 }" expression for both the link.

Step 5: The links will change to

```
<li><a href="" ng-click="activelink=1" ng-class="{ 'linkcolor' : activelink==1 }" </a></li>
<li><a href="" ng-click="activelink=2" ng-class="{ 'linkcolor' : activelink==2 }"</a></li>
```

The expression activelink==1 will return true or false depending on the value of activelink.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) , it has active states (these are the pages of your app) which do all these css and state changing from the view rather than having the logic in your controller and there are many powerful tools to make your app function better in less code..

In your nav:

```
 <ul>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
    <a href ui-sref="route1">route1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And thats it! Your currently active state/ view will apply the ui-sref-active="active" class to that li element. where "active" is the class name which is applied.